# Post http://localhost:5000/api/insert 404 not found error

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm getting error 404 (not found) in axios.post even my link is correct can any one help me how to fixed that
This is the respuest that I'm making

```
  Axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/insert")
    .then((res)=>{
      alert("Succefuly enteried data");
    }).catch((e)=>{
      console.log(e.response.data);
    });
```

and this is the backend code

```
app.get("/api/insert",(req, res)=>{

    const f_name = "ali";
    const l_name = "ahmed";
    const u_name = "afaq";
    const pass = "12345";
    const email = "afaqsabghatullah@gmail.com";
    const dob = "2000-12-10";
    // console.log(f_name)
    const Insert = 'INSERT INTO user(user_name,first_name,last_name,password,email,dob) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'
    var re='';
    db.query(Insert,[u_name, f_name,l_name,pass,email,dob],(err,result)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            re = err;
        }else
         console.log(result);
         re = result
    });
    res.send(re);
})
app.listen(5000, ()=>{
    console.log('running on 3001');
})
```

Please let me know what is the mistake that I'm making here.

Answer (score 2):

You have defined the API as GET but you are making a POST request using axios